# Thread-safe way of instantiating optional Realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

What I am trying to do is set up a series of AVPlayers which can be accessed via instance variables. Everything is stored in Realm and I've instantiated Collection with all the Realm vars in the previous view. Once the view loads, I want to load all the players, and then trigger them using some parameters from location. The thing is, when `locationManager` gets called, the player returns `nil` on the Player instance.

I'm guessing this is due to `locationManager` being called on a separate thread? What would be the thread-safe way of making sure the players have been instantiated if that is the case?

Here's the view with `locationManager` and the loader

```
class WalkMapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    /* …lots of outlets */
    var collection:Collection!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        /* …lots of other init stuff */
        self.loadPlayers()
    }

    func loadPlayers() {
        // get a url from somewhere
        for (i,_) in self.collection.players.enumerated() {
            // loop through the players and load them
            self.collection.players[i].player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
        for (i, _) in self.collection.players.enumerated() {
            self.collection.players[i].play()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the heavily shortened Collection class which is a Realm object and which has `players` in ignoreProperties.

```
class Collection: Object, Mappable {
    var players = List<Player>()
}
```

This is the Player class which is also a Realm object embedded in Collection, and has `player` in ignoreProperties

```
class Player: Object, Mappable {
    var player:AVPlayer?
}
```

Comment: This most probably doesn't have anything to do with threading, if you tried to access `Realm` objects from another thread, you would get an error and not a nil object. Is it this line: `self.collection.players[i].play()` that returns nil?

Comment: Yes @DávidPásztor, correct. In the `loadPlayers()` scope the player is accessible.

Comment: sadly this is the expected behaviour and as I suspected, it has nothing to do with threading, but with ignored properties. See my answer with a full explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem exists due to the fact that you are using *ignored properties*, which are not persisted by `Realm`. According to [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4877) GitHub issue about ignored properties, what you experience is the expected behaviour.

From the linked issue:

> "Ignored properties are only guaranteed to be consistent across
>   individual Swift instances, but retrieving an object from a collection
>   creates a new Swift instance each time, thus the behavior that you
>   see."

This means that the `self.collection.players[i]` inside `locationManager(didUpdateLocations:)` is actually a new Swift instance of the same `Realm` object that you created in `loadPlayers()`, which is not an issue with normal `Realm` properties, since they are fetched from the `Realm` database, but is causes an issue with ignored properties, since they are linked to a specific `Swift` instance and only exist in memory. Hence, when you retrieve a specific object from a collection (`Player` instance from `List'), all ignored properties are lost.

To sum it up, you won't be able to use ignored `Realm` properties in collections.

Comment: Brilliant, elegantly summed up. Thanks for untangling the problem. This may be a style question, but in your opinion what would be the best way to store the AVPlayers? As a property on the view (perhaps as a dictionary with a ref to the Player)?

Comment: Thanks :) Glad I could help, it's actually an interesting implementation question regarding Realm, so I'm glad I came across your question and looked into it. There is no one good way of solving this, but yes, storing the AVPlayers as properties of the view controller seems like a decent solution. Whether you store them in a dictionary or in an Array (since you stored them in a List in Realm an Array seems like the natural alternative) is completely up to you. Just decide which is the easier way (by index or by key) for looking up the AVPlayer instances and go with that implementation.

Comment: I was lead down the garden path a little by the `Realm` docs which say that ignoredProperties are absolutely normal properties in every regard. Thanks for the help regarding implementation, I'll probably put them in a singleton as I need them in other views.

Comment: Yeah, the docs are a bit misleading in this particular topic. Before looking for GitHub issues, I was looking at the docs as well, which didn't provide any help on this problem.